# elasticsearch wildcard regex match a specic pattern

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I want to match a specific pattern on data.@message field, the pattern look like :

> work def15b10e5784b918ebdd82e18f050e8 on blue

> work fc14d249afa54069a89e2a70b256b102 on green

> work 1026a5a9b9a74d5aac158ba88c080da1 on blue

> work 13942d32e5d841fe91216bbee4bda614 on green

I want to filter blue and green informations

```
{
  "wildcard": {
    "data.@message": "work[[:blank:]][0-9a-f]{32}[[:blank:]]on[[:blank:]]blue"
  }
}
```

how change regex to work on elasticsearch

Comment: Maybe `"data.@message": "work [0-9a-f]{32} on (green|blue)"`?

Comment: If you need a Grok pattern, try `%{WORD:name} (?<uuid>[a-f0-9]{32}) on (?<color>green|blue)`

Comment: but, I don't ant to use grok, cannot do it without ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to search documents and trying to match a regular expression use: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

If you are trying to extract this data into fields you could use an ingest pipeline with grok with the following patterns:

```
MESSAGE work [0-9a-f]{32} on
COLOR green|blue
```

and the following grok pattern
`%{MESSAGE:message} %{COLOR:color}`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html

This would allow you to filter on green and blue.

[image: Example of grok filter]

Comment: thanks for your replying, but I used grok debbuger and it return me :
{
}
what is means ? it look likes it catch nothing

Comment: @looock78976 I added a picture to my answer to show exactly what I did in the grok debugger. I am working on the latest version - 7.13

Comment: but, I don't ant to use grok, cannot do it without ?